# How to enable crypttab to run at boot

Tags: boot, cryptsetup

The cryptdisks service is set to run levels 0 and 6.

However, I don't know if this is a correct setting because perhaps crypttab is made to run in some other fashion.

In either case, this is a default 12.04.3 install. This is the crypttab entry:

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sda8 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

and fstab entry:

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

but at boot it is specifying that the /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 disk is not available and to either wait, resolve manually or skip.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. My issue was that cryptsetup was not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
```

Even though I could run the 'cryptsetup' command there appears to be additional stuff you need in the above mentioned package.
You can test with the following:

```
sudo cryptdisks_start cryptswap1
```

Then check /dev/mapper to see if you have the device 'cryptswap1'
Then this:

```
sudo cryptdisks_stop cryptswap1
```

The 'cryptswap1' device in /dev/mapper should now be gone.